# How to assign a Javascript array through it's indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically creating keys in javascript associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351495/dynamically-creating-keys-in-javascript-associative-array)

usually we initialize an array like this:

var ar = ['Hello', 'World'];

And for access to it's values we do:

alert(ar[0]); // Hello

But I want a custom index to assign, ex:

var ar = ['first' => 'Hello', 'second' => 'World'];

and then

alert(ar['first']);

But I can't find how, is there something like this that I could do for assign?

Thank's!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/351723/1238887

Comment: There is no such thing as associative arrays in JavaScript. You either have arrays with numeric indices, or you have objects: unordered collections of keys and values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) instead of Array, you can specify named properties for object

```
var ar = {
  first: 'hello',
  second: 'world'
};
alert(ar['first']);
```

Also you can just assign properties with string keys to your array, this will also work:

```
var ar = [];
ar['first'] = 'first';
alert(ar['first']);
```

Comment: Actually I didn't know I could access to an object's node as a string key, but now I know, Thank's to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an Object.

```
var obj = {'first': 'hello', 'second': 'world'};

alert(obj.first);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var ar = {
   'first' :'Hello', 
   'second' : 'World'
 };
```

As you can see, this is the way you initialize objects in Javascript.  Javascript blurs the lines between associative arrays and objects.

You can then access this with:

```
ar['first']
```

Or even:

```
ar.first
```

Also, you could leave out the quotes in the key initialization, like so:

```
var ar = {
   first :'Hello', 
   second : 'World'
 };
```

Comment: Note that this isn't an array anymore. (But it never was -- proper arrays don't have named indexes.)

Comment: Please explain the differences between his array form `['value']` and your object-form `{'key' : 'value'}`.

Comment: @DavidThomas: This is just the way you initialize hashes/objects in javascript.  Javascript blurs the lines between the two.  You can do ar['first'] at this point or even ar.first.

Comment: Thank's! Yeah I know this is an object, but it works for me as well, I just want to get the indexes through a class parameter for send it's value to a php file, again Thank you very much :)

Comment: @user1161318, yeah, I know. I was asking you to explain for the OP's benefit... =)

Comment: @DavidThomas: Oops!  I will go ahead and edit the answer.  Good call.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in JavaScript are just property bags (hashtables).

You can:

```
var ar = {};
ar["name"] = "Dave";
ar["salary"] = "Millions";

alert(ar.name);  //Dave
alert(ar["salary"]);  //millions
```

JavaScript allows you to be pretty flexible in how you create these objects.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays as such, but object literals:

```
var obj = {foo:'bar'};
obj.something = 'else';
//or:
obj['foo'] = 'BAR';
```

JS won't make a fuss if you create named indexes on an array (because the Array object traces back to the Object prototype) but you'll loose all use of `Array` features (methods like `sort`, or the magic `length` property, to name just a few)

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
    var h = new Object(); // or just {}
h['one'] = 1;
h['two'] = 2;
h['three'] = 3;

// show the values stored
for (var k in h) {
    // use hasOwnProperty to filter out keys from the Object.prototype
    if (h.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        alert('key is: ' + k + ', value is: ' + h[k]);
    }
}
```