# Construct a JavaScript object dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to populate an array of objects, so that the array should be attached to a grid. This is the format that I require:

```
data.push({ id: 1, values: { "country": "uk", "age": 33, "name": "Duke", "firstname": "Patience", "height": 1.842, "email": "patience.duke@gmail.com", "lastvisit": "11\/12\/2002" } });
```

I have key-value pairs of `values`, I am not sure exactly how would I be constructing the above object in a loop...??

EDIT:

I have this so far, but I am only adding values, not their respective keys:

```
var recordValues = [];
//for loop iterator
recordValues.push(colValues[colCount]);
//end for

data.push({ id: recordID, values: recordValues });
```

`colValues` contain the following: "uk", 33, "Duke"...all the possible values in an object..

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the data you're starting with?

Comment: Please don't confuse JavaScript objects with JSON objects.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I have made the edit.

Comment: You should have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/351723/218196.

Comment: @faizanjehangir What I really want to see is what `colValues` looks like; without knowing that it's difficult to tell how you go from that to the structure you want.

Answer (score 0):

If understand you correctly:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    var person = people[i];
    data.push({ 
        id : i + 1,
        values : { 
            country : person.country, 
            age : person.age, 
            name : person.surname, 
            firstname : person.firstname, 
            height : person.height, 
            email : person.email,
            lastvisit : person.lastvisit 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what is needed, but I need an object encapsulate all the fields of values..

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in keyValuePairs) {
  if (keyValuePairs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    data.push({ id: key, values:keyValuePairs[key]);
  }
}
```

[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) filters out prototype properties

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
var recordValues = [];
for (var value in colValues) {
   recordValues.push(colValues[value]);
}

data.push({ id: recordID, values: recordValues });
```