# cannot iterate through array and change value in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have to iterate through an array, change one of its values, and create another array refelecting the changes.

this is what I have so far:

JS:

```
var arr = new Array();

        arr['t1'] = "sdfsdf";
        arr['t2'] = "sdfsdf";
        arr['t3'] = "sdfsdf";
        arr['t4'] = "sdfsdf";
        arr['t5'] = "sdfsdf";

        var last = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            arr['t2'] = i;
            last.push(arr);
        }

        console.log(last);
```

Unfortunately, these are my results

[image]

As you can see, I am not getting the results needed as 0,1,2.. instead I am getting 2, 2, 2..
This is what i would like my results to be:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please let me know if you need me to explain more in detail

Comment: Arrays in javascript do not use textual indexes (meaning no associative arrays). What you are actually doing is adding properties onto the array object and not adding elements to the array.

Comment: I see. How would you fix or redo this code?

Comment: can you please provide me with an answer that shows code so that I can give it a try?

Comment: Use an object `{}` not an array `[]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically creating keys in JavaScript associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351495/dynamically-creating-keys-in-javascript-associative-array); specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/351723/7469) covers it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make a copy, otherwise you are dealing with reference to the same object all the time.  As it was said before - javascript does not have associate arrays, only objects with properties.

```
var arr = {}; // empty object

arr['t1'] = "sdfsdf";
arr['t2'] = "sdfsdf";
arr['t3'] = "sdfsdf";
arr['t4'] = "sdfsdf";
arr['t5'] = "sdfsdf";

var last = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
   var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)); //create a copy, one of the ways
   copy['t2'] = i;  // set value of its element
   last.push(copy); // push copy into last
}

console.log(last);
```

ps: you can use dot notation `arr.t1` instead of `arr['t1']`

Comment: Finally someone tries to help me here instead of criticizing. I will give your answer a shot. Thank you.

Comment: I tried you answer but the result loses the information in t1,t3,t4,t5.

Answer (score 1):

The array access with ['t2'] is not the problem. This is a regular JavaScript feature.

The problem is: You are adding the SAME array to "last" (5 times in code, 3 times in the screenshot).
Every time you set ['t2'] = i, you will change the values in "last" also, because they are actually just references to the same array-instance.

You must create a copy/clone of the array before you add it to "last".

This is what will happen in all languages where arrays are references to objects (Java, C#...). It would work with C++ STL though.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am normally a PHP programmer and its probably why I came across this bump. I will take your advice into consideration.